# Microsoft Exchange bandwidth out of control?

Tags: exchange

Yesterday afternoon I synced my Galaxy S II with Microsoft Exchange and my multinational corporation's exchange server. Mail settings were to push at all times.

Over night my phone drained its battery completely and rang up 550MB in mobile ***upload*** charges via Exchange. I'm certain it was exchange because I have a traffic monitor tool and that particular email client is only holding my exchange account.

This was, to understate, surprising.

Is this normal behavior for Exchange? I only received 8 emails over night, none of which had any attachments to speak of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I finally figured this out, after racking up 800MB of upload and 3.5MB of download with my Exchange Email over 2 days... I had tried to send someone an 8MB PDF and it never sent successfully... so it tried again, and again, and again, and again.

The email was stuck in my outbox and couldn't be deleted. I'd get "server error" messages (DERP!). The solution was to de-couple the device from Exchange, completely removing that account, thereby deleting the message, and then re-registering the device.

Now all is as it should be...

Long story short -- keep an eye on your outbox!